# Does SQLIte have Array Functions and Operators?

Tags: sqlite

Does Sqlite have array functions and operators as PostgreSQL does?

For example: `ARRAY[]`, `array_union` or `unnest`?

Comment: What did you find when you read the SQLite [manual](http://sqlite.org/lang.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has [table-valued functions](https://sqlite.org/vtab.html#table_valued_functions), which are, e.g., used in the [JSON1 extension](http://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) to allow a function to return multiple rows.

But there is no array data type; these are useful only for accessing external data (e.g., JSON arrays are represented as strings in SQLite).

Comment: Thanks for your comment!